# Using quotes when referring to word as word

Tags: sentence, quotes

In the example

> I did not think about using the word "about".

I feel that the word, *about*, should be wrapped in quotes. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a perfectly acceptable answer, especially when it is hand-written. When typing on a computer, you have also the possibility to *italicize* the word.